# How can Paul justify a following rock? 1 Cor 10:4

Tags: hebrew-bible, new-testament, pauline-epistles

The Bereans were known for checking the Scriptures which would have been the OT (and possibly other writings outside of our OT) when it came to Paul’s claims

If the Bereans were to check Paul in this verse

> “*and all drank the same spiritual drink. For they drank from the spiritual **Rock that followed them**, and the Rock was Christ*.”
>   ‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭10:4‬ ‭

Where would they look to justify his words. What rock is he referring to, how did it follow and what water did it give forth as drink?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate [... In what sense was Christ the Rock that followed .. ?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/in-1-corinthians-104-in-what-sense-was-christ-the-rock-that-followed-the-jews).

Comment: The Bereans where praised for actually caring for the truth, and giving Paul the benefit of a doubt as it were, and reading the Scriptures he mentioned, not for questioning Paul's apostolic authority—it doesn't matter whether you agreed with the apostles' interpretation in Acts 15 of Scripture on the binding nature of circumcision for Gentiles.

Comment: I’m not sure I implied the questioning of office as emissary to the Gentiles, I merely implied that the Bereans didn’t take even Paul’s words at face value without filtering them through the Scriptures. In other words everything in the NT is foreshadowed in the Old. So what was Paul pointing to in the OT to justify his claim?

Comment: I appreciate the link @NigelJ I’ll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a muse - Saul/Paul being a good Jewish rabbi was likely aware of the midrash surrounding the "rock" Moses struck that brought water in Exodus 17 - and how the Israelites didn't have an issue with water again until after his sister Miryam died (Numbers 20) - at which point they had another issue re water which led to Moses striking the "rock" again. Midrash (not text) speaks of them actually carrying the "rock" around the desert which provided them this "living water" ergo we see the connection Saul/Paul might be making to the rock in the desert & Jesus. 2nd Testament authors being Jewish often referred to Jewish midrash and other Jewish writings of their day.  Yes the related question Nigel J referred to has more to say on this.  Shalom!